# What is the total number of deaths world-wide in 2020?

Tags: data-request, demographics, global

This is a very simple question. I'm looking for the total number of deaths in 2020 world-wide. We are already well into 2021 - the statistics from 2020 should be available - yet I couldn't find the simple total number of deaths that occurred in 2020 world-wide.

Comment: Most of the datasets are projection based. But this github repository of [World Mortality Dataset](https://github.com/akarlinsky/world_mortality) is different. However, it doesn't cover all the countries.